# Font-awesome icons not showing when using IE via remote.modern.ie

Tags: font-awesome, modern.ie

I decided to test Microsofts IE test tool, [remote.modern.ie](https://remote.modern.ie/), and noticed that the font-awesome icons will not show on the [font-awesome site](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/). I had a look in the console, but no errors showed up.

Is this the case with all remote desktop sessions (in IE), or is it a remote.modern.ie issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue in RemoteIE (loading external fonts) and will be fixed in a VM update soon.

Source: I'm the PM of this service.

**Edit:** The service has been updated and this doesn't seem to happen. If you still have the same error please let me know.